# java 8 predicate type mismatch, this code seems logical to me

Tags: generics, java-8

This code seems logical to me, why the compiler is complaining about the predicate isBondAsset having the wrong type ?

I mean a "Predicate of any type that extends Asset" is a "Predicate of any type super of any type that extends Asset" or i'm wrong ?

```
private static class Asset
{
    public enum AssetType
    {
        BOND,
        STOCK;
    }

    private final AssetType type;
    private final int value;

    public Asset (AssetType type, int value)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public AssetType getType ()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public int getValue ()
    {
        return value;
    }
}

private static class AssetUtils
{
    public static int totalBondAssetValues (Collection <? extends Asset> assets)
    {
        Predicate<? extends Asset> isBondAsset = asset -> Asset.AssetType.BOND.equals(asset.getType());

        return assets.stream().filter(isBondAsset).mapToInt(Asset::getValue).sum();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why won't you use `Predicate<Asset>`? This is polymorphic in `Asset` and then will accept any subtype of `Asset`, isn't it what you want?

Comment: yes i know @Jean-BaptisteYunès but i want to stay flexible with my types as possible

Comment: Then read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès can you explain to me the reasoning behind the comment i posted to the answer below or i'm going wrong with it ?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès the link you pointed me to seems logical to me, but i still can't wrap my head around the error i'm getting in this example.

Comment: From the link, you can't *add* nothing to the predicate (a predicate has a method `test` that *consume* an argument, this is similar to a method add of a collection, you *inject* something to the predicate). So you need to use `super` to be able to *inject*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's give names to the two type variables:

```
Collection<T> assets;
Predicate<R> isBondAsset;
```

Compiler knows that both `T` and `R` are subtypes of `Asset` but that's all it has to go on.  In order for  `Predicate<R>` to be applicable to `Collection<T>` `R` must be a supertype of `T`, but you never declare it as such.

There is no reason for you to declare `isBondAsset` with a wildcard.  You should simply make it a `Predicate<Asset>`.  Then the code will compile because the compiler knows that `Asset` is a supertype of any type that satisfies `? extends Asset`

Comment: Let R be a type that is equivalent to <? extends T>, a Stream <R>'s filter method must be of type Predicate <? super R>. In my case i gave the filter method the type Predicate <R> which is valid in the context of Predicate <? super R>

Comment: Your stream is parametrized by `T`, which `extends Asset`.  Your predicate is parametrized by `R` which also `extends Asset`.  It is NOT the case that  `T extends R` or `T super R`.

Comment: This is a common source of confusion.  When `<? extends Asset>` appears twice in the same method, compiler will not assume that they refer to the same type.

Comment: I totally grasped your answer, i changed my predicate isBondAsset to Predicate <? super Asset> as <? extends Asset> is always valid in the context of <? super Asset>

Comment: Correct.  A type that satisfies `<? super Asset>` is a supertype of any type that satisfies `<? extends Asset>` and so the compiler will let you do this.  But you really should consider just making it a `Predicate<Asset>`.  Wildcards are mainly meant for method parameters.  Using it like this for a local variable is a good way to cause confusion.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Stream#filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-)

```
/**
 * Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream that match
 * the given predicate.
 *
 * <p>This is an <a href="package-summary.html#StreamOps">intermediate
 * operation</a>.
 *
 * @param predicate a <a href="package-summary.html#NonInterference">non-interfering</a>,
 *                  <a href="package-summary.html#Statelessness">stateless</a>
 *                  predicate to apply to each element to determine if it
 *                  should be included
 * @return the new stream
 */
Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate);
```

so it should be

```
 Predicate<? super Asset> isBondAsset
```

One of the main reasons for that, if I am not wrong, is possibility of using `Predicates` already defined for `<T>` super types:

```
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("1","22","3","44");

Predicate<Object> objectPredicate = o -> o.getClass().equals(String.class);

Predicate<CharSequence>  charSequencePredicate = ch -> ch.length() == 2;

Predicate<String> stringPredicate = s -> s.contains("2");

stringList.stream().filter(objectPredicate).forEach(System.out::println);

stringList.stream().filter(charSequencePredicate).forEach(System.out::println);

stringList.stream().filter(stringPredicate).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: a Stream <T>'s filter method has an argument of type Predicate <? super T>, a Stream <? extends T>'s filter method have an argument of type Predicate <? super ? extends T>, and an argument of type Predicate <? extends Asset> is a Predicate <? super ? extends Asset>, cause <T> can be a substitute in the context of <? super T>